# Shrink leather sandals

Tags: shoes

I have some all leather sandals and the straps have stretched. I have tightened the straps but I am running out of holes.

Can I shrink them by soaking them in water?

Comment: Soaking and then drying in hot sand will shrink leather, but also makes it very stiff.

Comment: Hot sand is not practical for me. :-)

Comment: @fixit7 Wouldn't it be more practical to cut new holes into the leather? Soaking leather in water often makes it very stiff, even without hot sand.

Comment: Soaking in hot water can stretch leather straps, belts, etc. It's not kind to the finish either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider removing the buckles or other hardware and attach patches/strips of Velcro fasteners.

The Velcro can be stitched, or glued to the parts that "mate" for an adjustable closure. Then, you'll be able to better find a comfortable versus a secure position for the straps.

Good Luck.

Comment: Velcro might work, but sewing will be a bit of work.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your sandals in sunlight ,then it will again get their orignal size.or if you put some warm water in a plastic bag then the bag put in your sandals for some time it is also useful way to resize your shrink sandals.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hole puncher and make new holes.

In future don't do them up so tight.

Comment: If I don't tighten them, the strap slips off the back of my heel.