# How to stop a leather ankle strap on sandals from sticking out

Tags: shoes

I have fairly small ankles, so I tend to wear sandals with ankle straps on their tightest setting. This means that often a fairly long piece of strap is sticking out. It doesn't affect the function of the shoes, but doesn't look nice. The straps are typically sown around the edges, so I cannot just cut the superfluous bit of strap off.
How do I stop the straps from sticking out? At the moment I use a bit of sewing thread to hold them in (making an extra loop), but that construction, while cheap, is fragile.

Comment: Well, one trivial "fix" is to buy sandals without straps, these days there should be plenty, and in fair prices, IMO. Unless you have reason to use sandals with straps?

Comment: Also, some answers [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/20727/shrink-leather-sandals?rq=1) might be useful in your case as well.

Comment: Ummm... sandals without straps are not very common here. Otherwise I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: Hence only a comment since it does not really answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an **IRON**IC lifehack to keep your sandals looking trim:

(It's a Dad Joke - This solution for the problem involves magnetism.)

It's a two-step process:

1. On the end of each strap, put a wide-headed iron thumbtack (point facing outward). Hammer the point down so that it bends to crimp the tack from falling out, and so that the point is harmless.
2. Attach (glue/epoxy) an appropriately-sized rare-earth magnet on the outside of each of your sandals to attract and hold the head of the tack on the loose strap. You may also want to smoothify the slight lump  with something like an adhesive-backed tape.

Here's a sketch of the idea…
[image: Magnet-thumbtack keeper for loose strap]
Before you commit yourself (epoxy, hammering thumb tacks flat, etc.), try a test using a small washer or coin taped to the end of each strap and a patch of tape to secure the magnet to the body of the sandal. Ironically, the attraction through the tape will not suffer much. You might even find a better way to conceal the pieces.

Good luck.

Comment: I think I might still have some neodymium magnets left over from some misguided undergraduate  experiment lying around, I could actually try this.